# Capture real-time command window output in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I execute a command using dos function in Matlab 2012a:

```
[status,output] = dos('example.exe','-echo');
```

During its execution, the command displays a string with the percentage processed, in the command window, and I want to use this information to create a `waitbar` in a GUI, but I can't use it "during" the execution. Is there any other way to get the command window content in real-time ? If not, what else can I do to make a waitbar for my command ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that with MATLAB's `dos` (or the related `system` and `unix`), because they (as you have already noted) are synchronous and only return once the application has finished.

What you need is to run the external program and your `waitbar` code asynchronously. This cannot be done in pure MATLAB code, but it's possible to do using Java (which can be used directly from MATLAB):

1. Write a class in Java that runs your program and collects the output asynchronously. See [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665104/executing-an-external-program-from-java-using-process-builder-or-apache-commons) for details.
2. Have your Java class call a MATLAB callback when new output data is read. The MATLAB callback can then update the waitbar. See [this post on undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/matlab-callbacks-for-java-events/) for more information.